# How to run tasks in Spark on different workers?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have following code for Spark:

```java
package my.spark;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class ExecutionTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("ExecutionTest")
                .getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        int slices = 2;
        int n = slices;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }

        JavaRDD<String> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(list, slices);

        dataSet.foreach(str -> {
            System.out.println("value: " + str);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        });

        System.out.println("done");

        spark.stop();
    }

}
```

I have run master node and two workers (everything on localhost; Windows) using the commands:

```
bin\spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

and (two times):

```
bin\spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<local-ip>:7077
```

Everything started correctly.

After submitting my job using command:

```
bin\spark-submit --class my.spark.ExecutionTest --master spark://<local-ip>:7077 file:///<pathToFatJar>/FatJar.jar
```

Command started, but the `value: 0` and `value: 1` outputs are written by one of the workers (as displayed on `Logs > stdout` on page associated with the worker). Second worker has nothing in `Logs > stdout`. As far as I understood, this means, that each iteration is done by the same worker.

How to run these tasks on two different running workers?

Comment: What is defined config including core numbers available on your machine and dedicated for workers ?

Comment: I have not changed anything from default.The workers have 4 cores each at workers info on the web console

Comment: I think the partition of the data is 1 and hence it is processed by only one worker . Try to repartition the data into 2 or more to see if that produces desired results

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Indeed, when I changed line creating dataSet to `JavaRDD<String> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(list, slices).repartition(2);` and increased `n = slices * 2` and then it looks like it is run on both workers. Similar behaviour was also visible, when  I changed `slices` value to 10 and `n = slices * 2`. However, when `n=slices`, changing repartition does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but I'm not sure if it will work correctly every time and everywhere. However, while testing, every time it worked as expected.

I have tested my code using host machine with Windows 10 x64, and 4 Virtual Machines (VM): VirtualBox with Debian 9 (stretch) kernel 4.9.0 x64, Host-Only network, Java 1.8.0_144, Apache Spark 2.2.0 for Hadoop 2.7 (*spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tar.gz*).

I have been using master and 3 slaves on VM and one more slave on Windows:

- debian-master - 1 CPU, 1 GB RAM
- debian-slave1 - 1 CPU, 1 GB RAM
- debian-slave2 - 1 CPU, 1 GB RAM
- debian-slave3 - 2 CPU, 1 GB RAM
- windows-slave - 4 CPU, 8 GB RAM

I was submitting my jobs from Windows machine to the master located on VM.

The beginning is the same as before:

```java
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config("spark.cores.max", coresCount) // not necessary
            .appName("ExecutionTest")
            .getOrCreate();
```

**[important]** `coresCount` is essential for partitioning - I have to partition data using the number of used cores, **not** number of workers/executors.

Next, I have to create JavaSparkContext and RDD. Reusing RDD allows for executing multiple times *probably* the same set of workers.

```java
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Integer> rddList
          = jsc.parallelize(
                    IntStream.range(0, coresCount * 2)
                             .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
               .repartition(coresCount);
```

I have created `rddList` that has `coresCount * 2` elements. The number of elements equal to `coresCount` does not allow for running on all associated workers (in my case). Maybe, the `coresCount + 1` would be enough, but I have not tested it as the `coresCount * 2` is not much as well.

Next thing to do is to run commands:

```java
    List<String> hostsList
        = rddList.map(value -> {
                Thread.sleep(3_000);
                return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            })
            .distinct()
            .collect();

    System.out.println("-----> hostsList = " + hostsList);
```

`Thread.sleep(3_000)` is necessary for proper distribution of tasks. *3 seconds* are enough for me. Probably the value could be smaller, and sometimes, probably, a higher value will be necessary (I guess that value depends on, how fast the workers get tasks to execute from master).

The above code will run on each core associated with the worker, so more than one per worker. To run on each worker exactly one command, I have used the following code:

```java
/* as static field of class */
private static final AtomicBoolean ONE_ON_WORKER = new AtomicBoolean(false);

...

    long nodeCount
        = rddList.map(value -> {
                Thread.sleep(3_000);
                if (ONE_ON_WORKER.getAndSet(true) == false) {
                    System.out.println("Executed on "
                            + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            })
            .filter(val -> val != 0)
            .count();

    System.out.println("-----> finished using #nodes = " + nodeCount);
```

And of course, at the end, the stop:

```java
    spark.stop();
```